# Update sphinx from source after apt-get

Tags: apt, sphinxsearch, sphinx

I'm running the latest debian as OS.

I installed Sphinx using

```
apt-get install sphinxsearch
```

However, I need to communicate with sphinx trough PHP. In order to do so I downloaded the latest Sphinx version to obtain the phpapi.

```
wget http://sphinxsearch.com/files/sphinx-2.0.5-release.tar.gz
```

When I try to perform a query I get an error about versions.

```
Query failed: searchd error: client version is higher than daemon version (client is v.1.25, daemon is v.1.22)
```

Apperently apt-get doesn't install the latest version. Doing an OS update and upgrade does not solve this either.

So I assume I have to update my sphinx installation from the downloaded source. Can I simply compile and install the source without losing data?

Or do you guys have another suggestion?

Comment: Are you using latest debian or latest stable debian? You can always try downloading 2.04 version of the phpapi?

Comment: Latest stable version of debian. I can't find the previous version, and I think I prefer updating sphinx.

Comment: You can have a look at testing and sid packages but they are "only" 2.0.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try uninstalling the default version of Sphinx, and using the latest Ubuntu/Debian package from http://sphinxsearch.com/downloads/release/ in order to take advantage of the latest version of the server.

Comment: could you give more specific instructions on how to properly uninstall sphinx without data loss?

Comment: Make filesystem and mysql backup before uninstalling. When you don't specify --purge during apt-get remove, good packages ask if they should keep the data, but I wouldn't rely on this.